# Black screen after installation

Tags: xorg, graphics, console

I have an Acer laptop with a Intel GMA4500MHD graphic card, after the installation of Ubuntu from an alternate install cd I get only a black screen after the grub selection pages.

I tried something in [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen) page and I still have the problem. I have tried with Debian testing and I have the same problem, it was alright on older Ubuntu and with debian Squeeze. I think that the kernel update includes some new drivers incompatibles with my graphic card.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions. You may need to boot a live CD and mount your ubuntu install to make the edits. Assuming your install is on /dev/sda1

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Now edit `/mnt/etc/rc.local`

```
gksu gedit /mnt/etc/rc.local
```

Add this line (avobe exit 0)

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B-0
```

Reboot.

If that fails, try appending your grub kernel (linux) line when you boot

Boot , when you see the grub menu, hit e to edit

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

If that works, add it to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,

If I start a liveCD I have the same problem, black screen, I try to install from alternate CD just for this issue so no solution on this way.

I tried to make it with grub modification with no result, the problem persists, it is not the backlight, i think that it is a resolution problem.

Comment: OK, you will have to try an older live CD so you can edit `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: If I connect a screen with VGA connector I see the beautiful login screen, so I'm going to modify it just now. Thank you :D

Comment: Great, once you find it, please post the solution for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 3):

(converted OP comment to answer)

I connected a screen with a VGA connector and now I see the beautiful login screen.

My solution indicates a hardware issue not a software problem.